# Bash parallel dd and mkfs

Tags: linux, bash, grep, dd

Hey you great coding folks,

At first I´m a total newbie in bash and only have some experience in Java.
Now it´s my task to make a script which makes it possible to flash a few hundred usb drives as fast and automatic as possible on a linux machine, which should not be changed.
So no Installation of more packages.

Okay now to the question:
I´ve splitted up the task to two skripts.

One filters lsusb and greps the right device and then starts a background process with the device id to copy over the image and do some partentioning stuff.

The main script meanwhile filters for new devices and creates a new background process for copying for them as well.
When there are no more suited devices left, the main script waits for all background processes to be finished and then asks the user to pull out all devices and stuck the next bunch in.

At the moment it works great apart from the dd in one background process waiting for the other one to finish. As they should run parallel and the processes which start the dd have different pids I have no idea why the wait.

Here is a part of the script:

The first parameter is the serial-number and the second is the name of the image file to be copied

Comment: So you start multiple instances of the posted script in the background, but they're running in serial? That's not up to this script. You should (additionally) post the script that does the backgrounding.

Comment: It's not the whole posted script thats running in serial, it's only the dd part.
With ps aux, i can see that all background processes i started are running, but there is only one dd process and when it finishes a new one starts.
    
I start the background processes in a loop with 
     ./flash.sh $temp_serial $Image&

Comment: There are some issues that will prevent the script from working correctly: `["$?" -ne "0"]` will never be true because of missing spaces. `for i in "${#pids_background[@]}"` will only ever loop once with i being the length of the array. `wait ${pids_background[i]}` assumes the loop variable will be the index, but it'll actually be the variable. Please fix these issues and then try again. [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much that other guy! spellcheck is incredible...
I´ve fixed the major errors in the scripts and changed some parts.
The Error remains the same.
As for two pluged devices both background processes get started and then for one i can see a dd process. After this dd finishes partprobe starts at the same moment as the dd process for the second device.
Any Ideas? I've edited the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to move the `sync` from line 8 to the line above `echo "all connected devices are flashed, please change devices"` or another line after you have waited (`wait $i`) for all operations to complete.